# Proof of a certain proposition not using classical logic

Tags: lean, lean3, constructive

I'm self-studying the textbook *Theorem Proving in Lean*, and there's one exercise from Section 3.7 that I'm stuck on. The exercise asks for a proof of the proposition ¬(p ↔ ¬p) that does not use classical logic. I've been able to prove the the proposition using classical logic by using proof by cases applied to p ∨ ¬p, but I don't know how to prove the proposition without the Law of Excluded Middle. Here is my classical proof:

```
open classical
example : ¬(p ↔ ¬p) :=
  or.elim
    (em (p))
    (λ h1 : p,
      λ h2 : p ↔ ¬p,
        iff.elim_left (h2) (h1) (h1))
    (λ h1 : ¬p,
      λ h2 : p ↔ ¬p,
        h1 (iff.elim_right (h2) (h1)))
```

For reference, a non-classical proof can use the following rules:

1. and.intro
2. and.elim_left
3. and.elim_right
4. or.intro_left
5. or.intro_right
6. or.elim
7. false.elim
8. true.intro
9. iff.intro
10. iff.elim_left
11. iff.elim_right

and a classical proof gets the additional extra rule:

12. em

Any help proving this proposition non-classically would be much appreciated!

Comment: A search on google finds [this third-party solutions repository](https://github.com/hyponymous/theorem-proving-in-lean-solutions/blob/a95320ae81c90c1b15da04574602cd378794400d/3.proofs.lean#L189-L208), which contains the proof you seek (and proofs for various other exercises). Of course there's no guarantee those proofs work until you ask Lean to check them!

Comment: This question already has an answer [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58496954/tpil-3-6-example-%c2%acp-%e2%86%94-%c2%acp)

Comment: That's very helpful! Thanks @Eric

Comment: This is one of my favorite logic puzzles for students learning logic.  It seems very difficult as written, but much more intuitive when negation is written as `-> false` and `false` is replaced with an arbitrary propositional constant `q`.  This only works because it is actually a theorem of minimal logic.

Comment: I didn't know about the generalisation, Jason, that's very cool!